# base64 javascript not running on iis, in some browsers too, why?

Tags: javascript, image, iis, loading

I have written some JavaScript code.  It works when running locally, but it is not working when hosted under IIS.  It also doesn't work under some browsers as well.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>SHOUT</title>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

    var base64;
    var img=document.createElement("img");
    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    function f()
    {
        alert("123");
        p=document.getElementById("picField").value;
        alert(p);
        img.setAttribute('src', p); 

        canvas.width = img.width; 
        canvas.height = img.height; 
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"); 
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0); 
        var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png"); 

        // debugger;
        //var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png"); 
        var r=dataURL.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "");
        base64=r;
        alert(base64);   
    }


    function getBase64Image()
    { 
        p=document.getElementById("picField").value;

        img.setAttribute('src', p); 
        var canvas = document.createElement("canvas"); 
        canvas.width = img.width; 
        canvas.height = img.height; 
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"); 
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0); 
        var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png"); 
        var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png"); 
        var r=dataURL.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "");
        base64=r;
        alert(base64);   
    } 
    </script>
  </head>
  <body id="index" class="home">
    <input type="file" id="picField"  onchange="f()" >

    <input type="submit" value="Post" class="submit" onclick="getBase64Image()"/>
  </body>
</html>
```

its working fine, but on iis not functioning, plz help

Comment: What do you mean by `not functioning` what is not working? Do you get any errors?

Comment: alert(base64) shows entire base64 code in local, but on iis it is showing only data'' , thats it, not converting image to base64 string

Comment: our aim is to upload files to server using html, javascript only

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is this: you are trying to load a picture from the client machine via Javascript.  You grab the value from the `<input type="file" />` and then immediately try to display it.  You can only do this on localhost with default IE settings.  Javascript is limited in an Internet scenario; you don't want client script accessing your file system and posting things to the server without your knowledge.

In fact, the line `alert(p);` in function `f()` should display a different value when running on your machine as opposed to being served from IIS.  From IIS, it should not display the complete path, just the file name.  How to work around this?  The easiest way is to add the site to your "Trusted Sites" list in Internet Options, but obviously you can't force your users to do this.

I have fought this battle before, and the only seamless solution I was able to come up with was to upload the picture to the server and *then* give the users a preview that they can manipulate.

The [new File APIs with HTML5](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/) will provide all the functionality you are looking for, but support is not across the board at this point.